# USB device error during boot

Tags: usb, 22.04, dmesg, xhci-hcd

I have a new computer with a MSI B650 Tomahawk mainboard. Everything works fine, but when booting 22.04, I get the following messages:

The part I am concerned about is this one:

```
[    1.073426] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

[    4.144270] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    9.440460] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   25.056459] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   25.364290] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   30.688457] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.304457] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.417586] usb usb1-port7: attempt power cycle
[   47.000292] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[   51.800366] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   56.812391] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   57.024408] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[   57.224293] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[   62.024420] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   67.036468] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   67.248293] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 12, error -71
```

What could this device be? I guess it must be something on the board, but how can I find out what?

Here is a more complete log of the USB-related messages...

```
[    0.359695] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.359695] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.359695] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.061173] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.061175] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.061177] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.061178] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.061179] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:0d:00.0
[    1.061300] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.061317] hub 1-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
[    1.061690] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.061707] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.061709] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.061710] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.061711] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.061712] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:0d:00.0
[    1.061787] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.061798] hub 2-0:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    1.062791] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.062793] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.062794] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.062795] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.062796] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:0f:00.3
[    1.062872] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.062881] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.064626] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.064643] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.064645] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.064646] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.064647] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.064648] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:0f:00.3
[    1.064729] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.064738] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.067139] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.067141] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.067142] usb usb5: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.067143] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.067144] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:0f:00.4
[    1.067231] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.067240] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.068878] usb usb6: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.068895] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.068896] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.068897] usb usb6: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.068899] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.068899] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:0f:00.4
[    1.068978] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.068986] hub 6-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.071941] xhci_hcd 0000:10:00.0: USB3 root hub has no ports
[    1.072389] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.072390] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.072391] usb usb7: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.072392] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.072393] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:10:00.0
[    1.072468] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.072477] hub 7-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.073336] usb usb8: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.073353] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.02
[    1.073354] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.073356] usb usb8: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.073357] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.073358] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:10:00.0
[    1.073419] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.073426] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[    1.380270] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.657327] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=2074, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.657332] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[    1.657334] usb 1-5: Product: ASM107x
[    1.657336] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Asmedia
[    1.666357] hub 1-5:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.671311] hub 1-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.761237] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.783509] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=3074, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.783514] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[    1.783517] usb 2-5: Product: ASM107x
[    1.783518] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Asmedia
[    1.790255] hub 2-5:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.790444] hub 2-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.976289] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.280969] usb 2-5.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.300501] usb 2-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8340, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.300503] usb 2-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.308570] hub 2-5.1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.308604] hub 2-5.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.400289] usb 1-5.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.544315] usb 1-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8342, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.544320] usb 1-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[    2.544322] usb 1-5.1: SerialNumber: 21020079DAEB
[    2.554351] hub 1-5.1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.557249] hub 1-5.1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.696429] usb 1-5.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.988421] usb 1-5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1130, idProduct=1620, bcdDevice= 1.87
[    2.988426] usb 1-5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.988429] usb 1-5.2: Product: USB  AUDIO  
[    3.076457] usb 1-5.1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.474434] usb 1-5.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825, bcdDevice= 0.12
[    3.474438] usb 1-5.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
[    3.474440] usb 1-5.1.1: SerialNumber: F1AA8D40
[    3.580474] usb 1-5.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.890260] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0db0, idProduct=422d, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    3.890262] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    3.890263] usb 1-6: Product: USB Audio
[    3.890265] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Generic
[    3.950506] usb 1-5.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[    3.950511] usb 1-5.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.950514] usb 1-5.1.2: Product: TTL232R
[    3.950516] usb 1-5.1.2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[    3.950517] usb 1-5.1.2: SerialNumber: FTGVJ52S
[    4.144270] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    9.440460] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   25.056459] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   25.364290] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   30.688457] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.304457] usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   46.417586] usb usb1-port7: attempt power cycle
[   46.496292] usb 1-5.1.5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[   46.596721] usb 1-5.1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=82ff, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   46.596726] usb 1-5.1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[   46.596729] usb 1-5.1.5: SerialNumber: 21020079DAEB
[   47.000292] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[   51.800366] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   56.812391] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   57.024408] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[   57.224293] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[   62.024420] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   67.036468] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   67.248293] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[   67.254113] usb usb1-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
[   67.448294] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[   67.842733] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b09, bcdDevice= 1.09
[   67.842738] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   67.842741] usb 1-8: Product: Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard
[   67.842743] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Corsair
[   68.064293] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[   68.363470] usb 1-9: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   68.378472] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1e7d, idProduct=2cf1, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   68.378477] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   68.378479] usb 1-9: Product: ROCCAT Kova Aimo
[   68.378481] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: ROCCAT
[   68.592293] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[   68.906784] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=1462, idProduct=7d75, bcdDevice= 0.01
[   68.906789] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   68.906792] usb 1-10: Product: MYSTIC LIGHT 
[   68.906794] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: MSI
[   68.906796] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: 7D7522120106
[   69.124293] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[   69.341684] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
[   69.341689] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   69.341691] usb 1-12: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[   69.355455] hub 1-12:1.0: USB hub found
[   69.355764] hub 1-12:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   69.407525] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   69.407527] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   69.408766] input: USB  AUDIO   as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2/1-5.2:1.2/0003:1130:1620.0001/input/input3
[   69.468512] hid-generic 0003:1130:1620.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [USB  AUDIO  ] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-5.2/input2
[   69.468589] hid-generic 0003:0DB0:422D.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Generic USB Audio] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-6/input7
[   69.469095] hid-generic 0003:0451:82FF.0003: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 0451:82ff] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-5.1.5/input0
[   69.469168] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B09.0004/input/input4
[   69.528568] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B09.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input0
[   69.528878] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B09.0005/input/input5
[   69.588570] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B09.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input1
[   69.588670] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/0003:1B1C:1B09.0006/input/input6
[   69.648577] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B09.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input2
[   69.648753] input: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:1E7D:2CF1.0007/input/input7
[   69.648887] input: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:1E7D:2CF1.0007/input/input8
[   69.708549] input: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:1E7D:2CF1.0007/input/input9
[   69.708680] hid-generic 0003:1E7D:2CF1.0007: input,hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-9/input0
[   69.708765] input: ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1/0003:1E7D:2CF1.0008/input/input10
[   69.768573] hid-generic 0003:1E7D:2CF1.0008: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ROCCAT ROCCAT Kova Aimo] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-9/input1
[   69.768737] input: MSI MYSTIC LIGHT  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:1462:7D75.0009/input/input11
[   69.768864] hid-generic 0003:1462:7D75.0009: input,hiddev3,hidraw8: USB HID v1.10 Device [MSI MYSTIC LIGHT ] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-10/input0
[   69.836743] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B09.0004/input/input12
[   69.896374] corsair 0003:1B1C:1B09.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input0
[   69.944831] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B09.0005/input/input13
[   70.004374] corsair 0003:1B1C:1B09.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input1
[   70.048624] input: Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/0003:1B1C:1B09.0006/input/input14
[   70.108391] corsair 0003:1B1C:1B09.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:0d:00.0-8/input2
[   70.706323] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   70.706335] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   70.711916] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[   70.719922] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   70.724478] usb 1-5.1.2: Detected FT232R
[   70.726001] usb 1-5.1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   70.816601] usb 1-5.1.1: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[   70.856415] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:0c.0/0000:0d:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1.1/1-5.1.1:1.0/input/input19
[   70.856483] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   72.257648] usb 1-5.1.1: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
[   77.133353] usb 1-5.1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   77.790330] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI from vendor?  I thought Asmedia issues had gone away. Have not seen them for a while. Old info, not sure if it still applies. The ASMedia 106x SATA controller chipset is buggy. 
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5819208#post5819208
The Solution: Linux kernel boot parameter "libata.atapi_passthru16=0"

Comment: I did flash the latest BIOS, but nothing changed. I will try the boot param you suggest, but am not at the computer right now. How do I see that the error is related to the SATA controller?

Comment: In the past users just removed any devices plugged into the ASmedia ports. Your motherboard  manual should show which are native to CPU and which are ASmedia.